# Shutdown leads to hibernation instead

Tags: windows-10, laptop, shutdown, hibernate

I've been attempting to shutdown my laptop via Start menu > Power > Shutdown, but for some bizarre reason the laptop goes into hibernation instead.
The (very lazy) solution from the laptop manufacturer is to reinstall the OS.

How else can I solve my problem?

Comment: Lol, the good ole reinstall request! I always wonder how many completely unnecessary reformat's they do per day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Windows hibernating when I shut down?](http://superuser.com/questions/1096371/why-is-windows-hibernating-when-i-shut-down), [How to instruct Windows 8 NOT to perform a fast shutdown?](http://superuser.com/questions/495240/how-to-instruct-windows-8-not-to-perform-a-fast-shutdown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast startup feature of Windows 10 is similar to hibernation. To disable it:

1. Open Control Pannel
2. Go to Power settings
3. On the left pannel, click "Choose the action of power buttons"
4. Uncheck "Activate Fast startup"

Note that my Windows is in French, so the exact names of options mat differ. Also, you may have to click "Modify parameters currently unavailable" to be able to uncheck this checkbox.