# systeminfo shows System Boot time several days ago

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop

I have noticed recently that my system boot time is only reset when I only restart the laptop .. When I shutdown the Laptop and turn on again it shows the old boot time .. I'm sure I shutdown the Laptop not sleep or hibernate .. it is not a problem for but I'm curious to know what is wrong 
I'm Running Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
And My laptop is Lenovo 310 aka (80TV)

Comment: this is since Windows 8 where the fast Start was added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 doesn't like to reboot, and sleeps whenever it can to make 'boot up' faster.

See
[Why is Windows hibernating when I shut down?](https://superuser.com/questions/1096371/why-is-windows-hibernating-when-i-shut-down)

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the instructions below. 
1.  Press Windows key + r ( + r).
2.  Type services.msc.
3.  Click Windows Time in the Name column.
4.  Alternate click and then click Properties.
5.  Change Startup type to Automatic (if it’s not already set to Automatic).
6.  Click Start if the service isn’t started.
Thanks,

Rashid Ashraf